# Generating string of numbers in random order

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to generate a string of the numbers 1-3 with the numbers in random order for each row selected from a table.

I have tried the following, but am unable to get the random numbers to change for each row (they are the same across all rows).

```
SELECT name
 , (SELECT LISTAGG( COLUMN_VALUE ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
    FROM TABLE( SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( '1', '2', '3' ) )
   ) AS q_order
FROM tableA
```

Desired Result:

```
NAME        Q_ORDER
-------------------
Name1       123
Name2       312
Name3       213
```

What I actually get:

```
NAME        Q_ORDER
-------------------
Name1       312
Name2       312
Name3       312
```

Version: Oracle 11.2.0

Comment: Do they all have to be permutations of {1, 2, 3}?  That is not entirely random; truly random should also allow 233, 131 and even 222 and 333.

Comment: And, if you want to know why your attempt failed: You have all the randomness isolated within a subquery, which is uncorrelated to the outer query. So the subquery is calculated only once, and the same value is used for every row in the outer query. You can force the subquery to be correlated, but you will get a very inefficient implementation of your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this... (simple but efficient). The second column is a string; if you need it as a number, apply `TO_NUMER()` to it. Of course, the values in the second column will be DIFFERENT every time you run the query (the values ARE indeed random!)

```
with
     tablea ( name ) as (
       select 'Name1' from dual union all
       select 'Name2' from dual union all
       select 'Name3' from dual
     )
select name,
       case floor(dbms_random.value(0, 6))
            when 0 then '123'
            when 1 then '132'
            when 2 then '213'
            when 3 then '231'
            when 4 then '312'
            else        '321' end as q_order
from   tablea
;

NAME   Q_ORDER
-----  -------
Name1  123
Name2  312
Name3  213
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will probably work with some tweaking.  Oracle would appear to be optimizing away the fact that the code should run for each row.

One method is to include an outer reference to bypass this optimization.  I think this is sufficient:

```
SELECT name,
       (SELECT LISTAGG( COLUMN_VALUE ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
        FROM TABLE( SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( '1', '2', '3' ) )
        WHERE a.name is not null
       ) AS q_order
FROM tableA a;
```

Comment: Why "should" the code run for each row? I already explained in a Comment (in which I offered exactly the solution you put in an Answer) why that is **not** the case. Why should a NON correlated subquery be calculated FOR EACH ROW?